# Dynamic IQueryable Join Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees, iqueryable, hotchocolate

**Background:**

Given the following two entities joint through one to one relationship:

```
public partial class Parent
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual Details Details{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Details
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long ParentId{ get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set;}
}
```

And having the following `Query` model:

```
public class Query
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Dob { get; set; }
}
```

**Question**

How can I apply the `Query` as `IQueryable` on the `Parent` (or `Details`) entity?

**Notes based on the use case I have:**

- `Query` class can't have two sub-classes for `Parent` and `Details` (it should be flattened)
- DB SQL query should fetch results that matches both conditions in `Parent` and `Details` (if condition fail for details, then parent shouldn't be in the results).
- There might be long list of optional fields in `Query` model. It means that the DB query should be dynamic and smart enough to know how to build the query and to know each field in `Query` belongs to which entity `Parent` or `Details` (i.e. I don't want a solution where I add conditions to check whether `Dob` exist in the `Query` or not)

**Use case:**

I'm using [HotChocolate](https://hotchocolate.io/) framework to integrate GraphQL which uses [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries) to build the queries. The issue I'm trying to solve is mentioned [here](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/issues/921)

Your support and suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to handle this issue by creating a `View` on the DB which joins both tables to act as single entity where I can filter, paginate and sort regardless whether it is one to one linked tables or it is single table.
Then did reverse engineering of that view using [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#reverse-engineering-of-database-views) to be integrated with EntityFramework and finally managed to handle `IQueryable` on both entities.

In case of any other option available and suitable for HotChocolate, please add another answer to enhance my existing solution.